# what does it mean when I am to create "andy.d/fine/temp" in linux terminal/tmux?

Tags: tmux

I assume it's neither a file nor a directory so I am sort of at a loss as to how to go about it.

tried creating it as a file and as a directory with the touch and mkdir commands respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Creating "andy.d/fine/temp" in a Linux terminal means that you need to create a directory structure where there is a directory named "andy.d" that contains another directory named "fine", and "fine" contains a directory named "temp".

To do this you can try one of these following commands:

```
mkdir -p andy.d/fine && touch andy.d/fine/temp
mkdir -p andy.d/fine/temp
```